# ¿Existe algún adjetivo que signifique "perteneciente o relativo a la imagen"?

Tags: adjetivos

Por ejemplo: ritual, como adjetivo significa "perteneciente o relativo al rito"

> El antiguo misticismo ritual

¿Existe algún adjetivo que cumpla esta misma función pero para describir algo relacionado a la imagen?

Gracias

Comment: En este [sitio](http://www.ideocentro.com/glosario.php?estudio_diseno_web_ideocentro=Glosario-de-terminologia-Web-tecnologia-y-diseno) describen **grafismo** como "perteneciente o relativo a la imagen" aunque la RAE define grafismo como **2. m. Expresividad gráfica en lo que se dice o en cómo se dice.** Tal vez agregar un poco más de contexto a tu pregunta sería muy útil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algunas opciones que tienes incluyen:

- **[iconográfico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KseEXQQ)**

  > 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la iconografía.
- **[pictórico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SwOyMIB)**

  > 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la pintura.
- **[visual](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bw5brFZ)**

  > 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la visión.
- **[gráfico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JPeHrNL)**

  > 2. adj. Dicho de una descripción, de una operación o de una demostración: Que se representa por medio de figuras o signos

Comment: (luego añado las definiciones, que estoy en el móvil)

Comment: Te añado links y definiciones de momento, y ya cuando tengas tiempo editas a tu gusto.

Comment: Una de estas tiene que servir aunque pienso que la pregunta necesita un poco de contexto ya que **imagen** tiene varias acepciones algunas en el arte, otras en lo relativo a personas, etc. Santiago que tal si explicas un poco más sobre lo que buscas.

Comment: @DGaleano Tienes razón, me faltó ser más específico. La definición de imagen a la que me refiero es _"Reproducción de la figura de un objeto por la combinación de los rayos de luz que proceden de él."_. En la sugerencia de guifa el adjetivo visual es el más cercano, sin embargo, no exactamente lo que busco.

Estoy describiendo un microscopio que no utiliza luz para generar imágenes, entonces quería escribir _"debido a que no utiliza luz en la producción (adjetivo que busco), siempre se obtienen imágenes monocromáticas."_

Comment: Ya se sale del contexto de esta pregunta pero tal vez puedas reescribir la frase como la que usa [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microscopio_electr%C3%B3nico) en la definición de microscopio electrónico **Un microscopio electrónico usa electrones en lugar de fotones o luz visible para formar imágenes de objetos diminutos**

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar [*iconográfico*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KseEXQQ)

> iconográfico, ca
>
> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la iconografía.

Ya que la [iconografía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KsZhO9s) es

> 1. f. Conjunto de imágenes, retratos o representaciones plásticas, especialmente de un mismo tema o con características comunes.
> 2. f. Representación o imagen de un personaje o de una realidad determinados.
> 3. f. **Sistema de imágenes** simbólicas.
> 4. f. **Arte de la imagen** o la representación plástica.
> 5. f. **Estudio de las imágenes** o representaciones plásticas en el arte.

Aunque puede ser que lo estés forzando un poco como "relativo a la imagen".