# Qué es "ritual" sintácticamente?

Tags: definiciones, sintaxis

Estaba viendo esta [pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21424/existe-alg%C3%BAn-adjetivo-que-signifique-perteneciente-o-relativo-a-la-imagen) y me ha entrado la duda de qué es `ritual` sintácticamente.

Siempre he pensado que `ritual` funciona como sustantivo hasta que busqué sobre esta, y vi que es un adjetivo. O sea, que frases como `el oscuro ritual` o `haremos un ritual` ¿están mal construidas sintácticamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ritual](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WWc6Z92) puede funcionar como sustantivo, no solo como adjetivo.

> 2. **m** <sub>(Nombre masculino)</sub>. Conjunto de ritos de una religión, de una Iglesia o de una función sagrada.

Funciona como adjetivo cuando significa

> 1. **adj**. Perteneciente o relativo al rito.

Pero como sustantivo cuando es sinónimo de [*rito*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WWY3A7w%7CWWYSKxR)

> 1. m. Costumbre o ceremonia.
> 2. m. Conjunto de reglas establecidas para el culto y ceremonias religiosas.